# Oracle SQL - Set consecutive numbers as a range

Tags: sql, oracle

This query returns the following results...

```
WITH t(wk, COST) AS
(SELECT wk, COST FROM myTable WHERE id = '345')
SELECT listagg(wk,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wk) AS wks, COST 
FROM   t
GROUP BY COST;
```

...

```
WKS               COST
----------------------
17, 18, 19, 21    446
26, 27, 28        588
```

Is it possible to create the following results where consecutive weeks are returned as from and to. (eg 1-10 rather than 1, 2, 3, 4,... etc)

```
WKS               COST
----------------------
17-19, 21         446
26-28             588
```

Comment: shouldn't the second line be '26-28' ?

Comment: Good spot! I'll change that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this problem you have to identify the sequence of consecutive weeks and group them. Here's my solution.

- Use the LAG function to identify any breaks in the sequence.
- Use the SUM function to assign a group number to each sequence.
- Find the starting and ending week in each group.
- Finally use the LISTAGG function to aggregate the result.

Query:

```
with x(wk, cost, startgroup) as(
    --identify the start of a sequence
    select wk, cost,
           case when wk = lag(wk,1) over (partition by cost order by wk) + 1
                then 0
                else 1
             end
    from mytable
    where id = '345'
    ),
    y(wk, cost, grp) as(
    --assign group number
    select wk, cost,
           sum(startgroup) over (partition by cost order by wk)
    from x
    ),
    z(wk, cost, grp) as(
    --get the max/min week for each group
    select case when min(wk) = max(wk)
                then cast(min(wk) as varchar2(10))
                else min(wk) ||'-'||max(wk)
                end,
            cost, grp
    from y
    group by cost, grp
    )
--aggregate by cost
select listagg(wk,',') within group(order by grp),
cost
from z
group by cost;
```

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ab87/6).

Comment: Gonna take a while to get my head around this, but it's exactly what I'm looking for... thanks!